# Laravel broadcasting: private channels not working due to auth error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, authentication, laravel-echo

First of all I would like to say that I know there are really a lot of topics about this subject. I read them allmost all, but without succes.

I am using Laravel Echo and Pusher in order to make websockets work. This actually works, for normal (read: non-private) channels. I receive the Javascript object in good shape.

Where the problem starts, is when I try to send something on a private channel. I get in my console the following warning:
`Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500`

This is due to a problem with authenticating the private channel, I guess. I tried to authenticate them in the following places:

BroadcastServiceProvider:

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        /*
         * Authenticate the user's personal channel...
         */
        Broadcast::channel('notification.{userid}', function ($user, $userid) {
             return true;
        });
    }
}
```

or routes/channels.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Broadcast::channel('notification.{userid}', function ($user, $userid) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
});
```

but none of this works. I also tried to change the wildcard to a `*`, instead of the `{userid}` but that doesn't work as well.

Pusher, though, shows the event in normal shape. So they are sent, only the receiving by Echo gives problems. My Echo configuration looks like this:

```
this.websocket = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'KEY',
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: false,
    authEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth'
});

this.id = 1;

this.websocket.private('notification.' + this.id).listen('CreditsSent', e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

I am using Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.x. Can someone please helpe, because I am lost.

Comment: check if you have un-commented the BroadcastServiceProvider line in app.php in config folder.

Comment: I have uncommented it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself. A while back, I updated my project from Laravel 5.3 to 5.4. I expected that channels.php, which I created manually, was imported automatically. Turned out that I had to import it within my `broadcastServiceProvider`.  Everything works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your application template must have `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in the `head` element or you can set `window.Laravel.csrfToken` before making a socket connection using `Echo`.

Ensure that `Echo` makes an authentication request that contains the `CSRF-Token` in the header.

You can verify this in the Network tab of your browser developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have the meta tag in my head, but I couldn't see the CSRF-token in the header. But then I saw that I got a 404 when requesting /broadcast/auth. I uncommented the service provider in my config/app, to enable the routes, but that still doesn't work.

Comment: 404: http://prntscr.com/gcfywx. Looks like the `Broadcast::routes()` in BroadcastServiceProvider doesn't add the routes for some reason.

Comment: Are the `BroadcastServiceProvider`s in config/app.php uncommented?

Comment: Both `Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` and `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` are uncommented

Comment: Is `/broadcasting/auth` in the output of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Useful command! Didn't know it exists. But yeah, it is in the list: http://prntscr.com/gci1dw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152777/discussion-between-oluwafemi-sule-and-galago).

Comment: @OluwafemiSule The chosen answer isn't particularly helpful, and you seem knowledgeable, could you please share the advice that was given in this chat?